# MSi installation Error

Tags: wix

have created MSI using Wix. When I am trying to install it, I am getting the below error.
"The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory c:\programfiles\AppTest.The installation can not continue log on as administrator or contact your system administrator".
I went through some of similar post but it did not helped me.Below in my code.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
<Product Name='AppTest' Id='*'enter code here
    UpgradeCode='{05E35D34-E7F6-4CED-BF86-B1747AE92E07}'
    Language='1033' Codepage='1252'
    Version='2.0.0.1'
    Manufacturer='LabView Inc' >

      <Package Id='*'
        Languages='1033'
        SummaryCodepage='1252'
        AdminImage='no'
        InstallerVersion='200'
        InstallPrivileges='elevated'
        Compressed='yes'
        ReadOnly='yes'
        ShortNames='yes'
        Comments='AppTest Installer Package'
        Description='AppTest Installer Package'
        Manufacturer='LabView Inc' />

        <Media Id='1' Cabinet='AppTest.cab' EmbedCab='yes' />

        <!--Directory structure-->
        <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
            <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder'>
                <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="AppTest"/>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

    <!-- Adding Components-->

    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Component Id="AppTest.dll" Guid="3947344C-8116-48FB-9F8A-080EA7D1ABAD">
        <File Id="AppTest.dll" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\AppTest.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
            <File Id="msvcp80.dll" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\msvcp80.dll" />
            <File Id="atl80.dll" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\atl80.dll"  />
            <File Id="msvcr80.dll" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\msvcr80.dll"  />
            <File Id="Microsoft.VC80.ATL.manifes" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\Microsoft.VC80.ATL.manifest" />
            <File Id="Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest"  />
            <File Id="AppTest.inf" ReadOnly="yes" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\AppTest.inf" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>


    <Feature Id="AppTestFeature" Title="AppTest" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="AppTest.dll" />

    </Feature>


</Product>
```

Comment: Your installer tries to write files to "C:\Program Files" directory. By default it is allowed to the members of Administrators group only. Also, if you have UAC enabled, and you are an Administrator, you have lowered privileges, and you must "Run as administrator" to install your program.

Comment: I have admin rights.

Comment: @bally check my answer, you just wanted to install in `TARDETDIR` (which was C:\) change to `APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY`

Comment: Yes I tried as suggested by you. It works only when UAC is turned off. If UAC is ON it prompts same error. I need to install the MSI either UAC is ON/OFF. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: @bally what version of WiX are you using?

Comment: @bally i'm using 3.8 and no problem with UAC :/ maybe thats reason??

Comment: BTW—You should have only one assembly's Files per Component and, for non-assembly Files, generally only one per Component. See [Organizing Applications into Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370561(v=vs.85).aspx) and linked articles.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `<CreateFolder Directory='AppTest' />` and change code to this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY"> <!-- main folder ur app -->
        <Component Id="AppTest.dll" Guid="3947344C-8116-48FB-9F8A-080EA7D1ABAD">
            <File Id="AppTest.dll" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\AppTest.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
            <File Id="msvcp80.dll" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\msvcp80.dll" />
            <File Id="atl80.dll" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\atl80.dll"  />
            <File Id="msvcr80.dll" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\msvcr80.dll"  />
            <File Id="Microsoft.VC80.ATL.manifes" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\Microsoft.VC80.ATL.manifest" />
            <File Id="Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest"  />
            <File Id="AppTest.inf" ReadOnly="yes" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)files\AppTest.inf" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply I modified the code as suggested, but still i am getting same error.

Comment: I made changes as suggested but MSI only works when UAC is turned off. But I need the MSi to be installed either UAC is on/off. Please provide your idea on this how to achieve it.

Comment: @bally [Check this article](http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/335-how-to-silence-the-uac-prompt-for-per-machine-msi-packages-for-non-admins)

Comment: If this is a per machine install then set InstallScope to perMachine, that probably won't solve the problem but if that's the goal then set it explicitly. Do you see an elevation prompt on UAC systems? That's the key to getting the rights to do that, assuming the installing user is admin. An install doesn't violate security rules and the installing user must have admin rights to write to that ProgramFiles location.

Comment: No I am not getting any UAC prompt during installation when UAC is turned on.

Comment: @PhilDW any furthuer inputs you would like to provide as i tried several option but still facing the same issue.

Comment: I added InstallScope permachine to your example above and I build, run and get elevation prompt on Windows 7. All I can say is verify your UAC settings are correct. You should see elevation or a prompt for admin credentials.